# Space of real/complex sequences and its basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider a space of sequences K^N , Is the set {bi |i∈N} ⊂ K^N with
bi =(0,...,0, 1 ,0,...) (1 being at the i-th possition)
(i∈N)
a basis of K^N?

well this set is clearly linearly independent and spanning, but why it is not the basis ?
what am i missing, please help!

Comment: Of course, it is a basis. It‘s even called the standard basis. (Assuming you mean a field with $K$.)

Comment: Hm on the other hand, I see that you probably mean $\mathbb{N}$ and not some integer $N$.

Comment: No, it is not. You are thinking about $K^N$, for some $N\in\mathbb N$. But here the space is $K^{\mathbb N}$, the space of all sequences of elements of $K$.

Comment: Linear combinations must be finite. This is the reason of why that set not spans the whole space.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the fact that it it does *not* span the whole space. It spans the set of those sequences $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ such that $a_n=0$ if $n$ is large enough. For instance, the constant sequence $1$ is not a linear combination of elements of your set.